# foreach как сделать каждый первый элемент в другом блоке?

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, acf

Сейчас такая конструкция

```
<?php
$repeater = get_field( 'portfolio-img' );
foreach( $repeater as $item ) { ?>
    <ul>
<?php foreach ( $item['portfolioimgg'] as $subitem ) { ?>
   

    <li> 1111 <?php echo $subitem['portfolioimgg-Img']; ?> </li>
   

     <?php } ?>
            </ul>
    <?php }?>
```

вот так выглядит вывод

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как сделать чтобы выводилось вот так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$repeater = get_field( 'portfolio-img' );

foreach( $repeater as $item ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ( $item['portfolioimgg'] as $index => $subitem ): ?>
        <?php if ($index === 0): ?>
            <li> 2222222222 <?php echo $subitem['portfolioimgg-Img']; ?> </li>
        <?php else: ?>
            <li> 1111 <?php echo $subitem['portfolioimgg-Img']; ?> </li>
        <?php endif; ?>         
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

---

если `$index` не числовой, то:

```
<?php
$repeater = get_field( 'portfolio-img' );

foreach( $repeater as $item ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php
        $index = 0;
        foreach ( $item['portfolioimgg'] $subitem ): ?>
        <?php if ($index === 0): ?>
            <li> 2222222222 <?php echo $subitem['portfolioimgg-Img']; ?> </li>
        <?php else: ?>
            <li> 1111 <?php echo $subitem['portfolioimgg-Img']; ?> </li>
        <?php endif; ?>         
    <?php ++$index; endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Очень помогли